# Не расширяется модальное окно в bootstrap на ios

Tags: ios, bootstrap

Есть страница написанная на bootstrap. На нем есть модальное окно. Есть глюк который производиться только на ios (с телефона). Если Модальное окно после загрузки страницы дополнить элементами (div,p , ul не важно) так что они перестанут умещаться по высоте экрана, то содержимое которое не поместилось явно уезжает за область просмотра а окно блокируется для прокрутки. Стандартные стили bootstrap я не переопределял.

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж никто не ответил , отвечу на свой вопрос сам так как нашел решение. Нужно дописать в файл со стилями:

```
body.modal-open {
     position: fixed;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```